# Root Directory?

Tags: html

I'm editing a file in a folder in my root directory.. here's a quick tree:

```
root
- images
- m
- - index.php
```

If I want to grab the images folder from index.php, how would I go about doing that? I've tried:

```
../images
```

I want to eliminate having to use my website URL.

Comment: Derp. My file wasn't saving correctly to my server. ../ was working all along. Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 6):

you should use `/images` instead of `../images` if you know the image directory is in the root. this will resolve to a directory named images in the root from any path.

eg if you are on page `/pages/html/MyPage.html` the path `/images` will still resolve to the images directory in root whereas `../images` would resolve to `/pages/images`.