# HTML root folder?

Tags: html

Is there a way to direct a url such as an image location to your root folder and then into a directory from there.

Currently i am using "../" to go back folders but this gets annoying if you have a complex directory tree.

Thanks

Comment: [Root Directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317806/root-directory).

Comment: the directory where you put index.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is just a single character:

```
/
```

For example:

```
/image.jpg
```

whatever page you put it in, it refers to the same file, root_folder/image.jpg

Comment: I've reverted your latest edit—you're confusing the path and hostname parts of the URL. The answer is correct as it's now.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `<base>` to set the base url all urls should be relative to. In general using an absolute path with `/` is probably prefereable, but `<base>` may be useful if you have the "root" of your page *not* on the root of the domain.  I.E. `example.com/mysite/index.html` vs. `example.com/index.html`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/base

Answer (score 3):

You can just use full Url, like:

```
http://domain.com/file_in_root_folder.jpg
```

or absolute paths

```
/file_in_root_folder.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use static addressing that start with http:// and for relational addressing you can use your address with / for example: /foo/bar.jpg